# Renting a car in Israel when under 21?

Tags: driving, car-rentals, israel

I'm going to be staying in Israel for the next 6 months, and I would like to be able to get around. I have a valid US driver's license, which is considered valid in Israel as well.

The problem however, is not with the license, but with the car. I don't own a car here, and I don't plan on buying one for only 6 months of use, so I decided that the best solution would be to rent/lease it.

The problem though, is that I am under 21. In the US, it is almost impossible to find a rental company that will rent a car to anyone under 21 (sometimes 25).

**Is that any different in Israel? Are there any car rental/leasing companies (anywhere in Israel) that will rent to someone under 21? Does Israeli law even allow it?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not any different in Israel. It will be hard for you to find a rental company that will rent to a driver under 21. I'm not sure it is at all possible.

But, fortunately you're going to Israel, not the US. Take a bus.

Comment: To expand on littleadv: In the US it is almost impossible to go anywhere without using a car. In Israel it is easy and cheap.

Comment: Just for the sake of comparison, the entire area of Israel is smaller than Vermont.

Comment: @JonathanReez Only without the Occupied Territories, correct?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus if you include the West Bank they're about the same